# Switch statement outputs wrong value for cost

Tags: c++, switch-statement, sleep, cout

When I try to run this code on Microsoft Visual Studio C++; It runs but the value of cost that is being outputted is wrong. Why is that? I do realize that I am not including a default statement, and that I am declaring `cost` twice, this is because I get the debug error that `cost` has no declared value, so what I assume is going on is the switch statement is not processing because it some how is not understanding the
     `cout << "Pizza";`
How do I fix this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, m, p, k,  User_Input, Pizza , cost;
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    d = 0;
    e = 0;
    f = 0;
    k = 0;
    cost = 0;

    cout << "What is your favorite vegetarian food from the list below?" << endl;
    Sleep(1500);
    cout << "Pizza\n";
    Sleep(200);
    cout << "IceCream\n";

    cin >> User_Input;
    switch (User_Input)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "Pizza";
        cost = 5;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "IceCream";
        cost = 5;
        break;

    }


    Sleep(2000);
    cout << "The total cost will be: " << cost;
    cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t";

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: you say it outputs the wrong value, what do you expect the right value to be?

Comment: by wrong value do you mean that it's outputting nothing at all?

Comment: It would be handy if you said what you input to the program when prompted, and what value you actually got as a result, rather than just saying "it gives me the wrong value". By the way, both `case` items set `cost` to `5`.

Comment: It outputs cost as 0

Comment: You don't have a `default`

Comment: What is your user input, "Pizza" or "1"?  It works if you use the int value, not the string.

Comment: I want it to use the string

Comment: Then you will need to do a string comparison on your input, not a switch on the integer

Comment: You could convert the strings to an integer hash (with something like djb2) and then use those values in the switch statement and the case statements.

Comment: Sleeping after the Pizza can make it cold; why the need to sleep?  Be a *real* programmer and eliminate the sleeping.

Answer (score 2):

User_Input is of type "int", you are going to get unexpected results if you try to read a string via cin to that variable.  What you probably want to do is either:

- read into a string and do a string comparison
- read into a string, convert to an int, and do the switch statement

A simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
        std::string user_input;
        int cost = 0;
        std::cout << "What is your favorite vegetarian food from the list below?\nPizza\nIceCream\n";
        std::cin >> user_input;
        if(user_input == "Pizza") {
                cost = 5;
        } else if (user_input == "IceCream") {
                cost = 10;
        }
        std::cout << "The total cost will be: " << cost << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I upvoted. I prefer the advanced option #2 you proposed. In the past in C programs I used a hash function like DJB2 (any good hash algorithm with low collisions will do).